# How can i sync two Lists according to another List?

Tags: c#, .net

```
ListsExtractions.dateTimeList = ListsExtractions.dateTimeList.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToList();
ListsExtractions.TextList = ListsExtractions.TextList.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToList();
FilteredLinks = FilteredLinks.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToList();
```

All the 3 Lists dateTimeList , TextList , FilteredLinks are type `<string>`

The first List dateTimeList i sorted by higher to lower. And it's fine as i wanted.
Now i need to sort the other two list to sync to the dateTimeList.
Before sorting the dateTimeList they were sync.
But now after sorting dateTimeList i need to sort the two others to the first one.

I tried to make OrderByDescending to other two Lists too but this is not the right way.

Answer (score 0):

For this type of sorting you need to union your data to one data structure (before sort). For example, you may union your 3 lists of strings in one list with `Tuple<string, string, string>` (but it's better to create specific type for your business logic). And then sort like this:

```
newData.OrderByDescending(item => item.Item1).ToList()
```

**Edit:** For creating list of tuples, you may use this (for example, you have lists with names `a`, `b`, `c`):

```
var newData = a.Select((x, index) => new Tuple<string, string, string>(x, b[index], c[index])).OrderByDescending(x => x.Item1).ToList();
```

You can look at example in dotnetfiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/kOh2bf

Comment: idlerboris i did like that: Tuple<List<string>, List<string>, List<string>> tuple = new Tuple<List<string>, List<string>, List<string>>(ListsExtractions.dateTimeList, ListsExtractions.TextList, FilteredLinks); but now tulp dosent have any OrderByDescending property. What did i do wrong ?

Comment: No, you need to create List<Tuple<string, string, string>>

Comment: So i need to loop over the Lists and add them each string to the Tulp ?

Comment: @user3816441, I exapnd my answer with example of creating this new list.